# How to recursive import to security group all members from Universal Distribution Groups in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, import, active-directory

How can I to import all the members of a universal distribution group in Active Directory into a security group? in many cases there are nested distibution groups. How can I get the members of each nested group?
I mean I will get recursive Group Membership of Distribution Group and all members import to the SG

Here is my command :

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity distributiongroup | ForEach-Object { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity securitygroup -Members $_ }
```

Error Message:

```
Add-ADGroupMember : A global group cannot have a universal group as a member
At line:1 char:124
+ Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "distribution_group" | ForEach-Object { Add-ADGroupMember <<<<  -Identity "SG_users" 
-Members $_ }
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (SG_users:ADGroup) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : A global group cannot have a universal group as a member,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered your own question :) just add the `-recursive` switch to your `get-adgroupmember` call